# CSSで、会社のロゴを左上、メニューを右上に配置したいのですが

Tags: html, css

CSS初心者なのですが、以下のようにhtml、CSSを書きました。
しかし、自分が想定したようなレイアウトとはかけ離れ、完全に崩れています。
どのサイトでも良かったのですが（デザイン参考サイトからこのページを選びました）、[このページ](http://mukai-koumuten.com/)のように、会社ロゴを左上、メニューを右上、そしてコンテンツをheader部以下に配置したいと思います。
cssのどの部分が問題、または設定が不足しているのでしょうか？
宜しくお願いします。

```css
       div#logo_area { float: left; }
       nav#menu { float: right; }
       ul.skinny { 
        display:table;
        table-layout:fixed;
        width:400px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
       }
       ul.skinny li {
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:center;
        border-left:1px solid white;
       }
       ul.skinny li:first-child { border:none; }
       ul.skinny li a {
        display:block;
        text-decoration:none;
       }
```

```html
    <html>
     <head>
      <style type="text/css">
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div id="nav_area">
       <div id="logo_area">
        <span><a href="">株式会社　ラララララ</a></span>
        <figure id="logo" background-image="url()"></figure>
       </div>
       <nav id="menu">
        <ul class="skinny">
         <li id="product">商品案内</li>
         <li id="order"><a href="">注文</a></li>
         <li id="company"><a href="">会社案内</a></li>
         <li id="inquery"><a href="">お問い合わせ</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>
      </div>
      
      <div class="contents">
       <div class="" style="background-color:Yellow;">Yellow</div>
       <div class="" style="background-color:green;">Green</div>
       <div class="" style="background-color:blue;">Blue</div>
       <div class="" style="background-color:Red;">Red</div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

floatを利用する場合、回り込み解除を意識しなければなりません。

解決方法は３パターン程あります。

1. floatを取り囲む要素の次の要素で回り込み解除する(clearプロパティ)
2. floatを取り囲む要素にoverflowプロパティを適用して解除
3. clearfix(:after擬似要素)で解除

#### 1. clearプロパティ

```
div.contents {
   clear: both;
}
```

#### 2. over-flowプロパティ

```
div#nav_area {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

#### 3. clearfix

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
   content: " ";
   display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
   clear:both;
}

//floatを取り囲む要素(#nav_areaにclearfixクラスを適用)
<div id="nav_area" class="clearfix">
```

どれを利用するかは対応するブラウザや、レイアウトの状況によって変わってきますが、現在では3.clearfixが主流になりつつあります。

[こちら](http://qiita.com/shizuma/items/e79702c915a557491884)で、上で説明した各解決手法がより詳しく説明されていますので参考までに。

Comment: Naさん　3パターンも教えて頂きましてありがとうございました。その後、自分でもclearfixについて調べ、学習いたしました。勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

CSSは、`ul.skinny`及び`ul.skinny li`に`width`を設定し、
`display: table`や`display: table-cell`を削除しました。

メインコンテンツがヘッダに食い込んでいたので、
`#nav_area`に、`overflow: hidden;`を追加しました。

いかがでしょうか？

```css
      #nav_area {
        background-color: #eee;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      #logo_area {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px 30px 0;
      }
      ul.skinny {
        float: right;
        width:650px;
      }
      ul.skinny li {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:center;
        border-left:1px solid white;
        width: 150px;
      }
      ul.skinny li:first-child { border:none; }
      ul.skinny li a {
        display:block;
        text-decoration:none;
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="nav_area">
      <div id="logo_area">
        <span><a href="">株式会社　ラララララ</a></span>
        <figure id="logo" background-image="url()"></figure>
      </div>
      <nav id="menu">
        <ul class="skinny">
          <li id="product">商品案内</li>
          <li id="order"><a href="">注文</a></li>
          <li id="company"><a href="">会社案内</a></li>
          <li id="inquery"><a href="">お問い合わせ</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>


    <div class="contents">
      <div class="" style="background-color:Yellow;">Yellow</div>
      <div class="" style="background-color:green;">Green</div>
      <div class="" style="background-color:blue;">Blue</div>
      <div class="" style="background-color:Red;">Red</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 空の`<div>`を使う方法がイマイチだったため修正しました。

Comment: @sujoyuさん　スニペットまで出して頂き、確認がしやすかったです。本当にありがとうございました。